# Should this question be left open?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

When I posted the question "[Mobile touch menu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56267/34757)" I was counting on someone else's report that they'd tested it and found it working on iPhone.

But then after [konijn's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56267/mobile-touch-menu?noredirect=1#comment99469_56267) I asked that it be retested and now I'm told that it doesn't work.

So apparently the implementation posted in the question doesn't work, and so I must rewrite it thoroughly.

What to do with that question now:

- Close it?
- Leave it open?
- Close it temporarily, until I can edit it with a better-working solution?

I'm no longer interested in the code in the OP (because it doesn't work).

As of now the question has a bounty, and no answers. Perhaps no worthwhile answers are possible (except for konijn's reviewing it to say that it doesn't work).

Comment: From my research, I think you will need JavaScript. You could write your own minimal library for that in say 3 days, and then I can review in 2 days ;)

Comment: @konijn I may not have time to write an alternate solution. Can you reformat your existing comment as an answer so that I can accept it? I might then post another, follow-up question in the future.

Comment: For 250 points I will at least attempt to write an alternate solution ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question cannot be closed while it has an open bounty.

Since it hasn't been answered yet, and there is a large bounty, I suggest leaving a comment to tell others not to review the code while you are in the process of rewriting the question. It's definitely bending the rules of Code Review, but I think it's the pragmatic thing to do in this case.

Comment: Is this also a case in which the bounty can be refunded at some point?